# Handlebars Template Not Rendering - Can See HTML In Firefox Inspector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars template in an external file (user-listing-template.html) which I am dynamically loading via a JQuery Ajax call to retrieve the file, compiling via Handlebars.compile and then displaying in a div. See example code below:

Template file:

```
<script id="user-listing-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <h2 class="ui header">User Maintenance</h2>
  <hr>
  <h4 class="text-align-left">Total Users: </h4>
  <br><br>
</script>
```

JS function to load Template:

```
function userListroute() {
var source;
    var template;

    $.ajax({
        url: "/templates/user-listing-template.html",
        cache: true,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Template Data From File: ' + data);
            source = data;
            console.log('Template HTML ' + source);
            template = Handlebars.compile(source);
            console.log('Compiled Template: ' + template);

            $('#app').html(template);

        }               
    });  
}
```

In index.html, I have a div where I would hope to see the template:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

However, when I run this application the template is not rendered. I can see the template's HTML code in the Inspector in Firefox dev tools:

[Firefox Inspector Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub161.jpg)

All of the console.log() statements show the valid HTML code is there, however it will not display, I only see the blank page. The console output is shown here:

[Firefox Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uheNm.jpg)

I am clearly doing something wrong, just not sure what - it all appears to be working except for the rendering bit.

Any assistance greatly appreciated. I'm fairly new to Handlebars, and am just trying a proof-of-concept application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you retrieve your template file you are leaving it encapsulated with `<script>` tags. Handlebars needs the content only. Thus (as you can see in Firefox inspector) the compiled output is not displayable HTML as it is still within the original `script` tags.

You need to extract the HTML from your data when you assign it to the `source` variable.

```
success: function( data ) {
    source = $( data ).html();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to official site http://handlebarsjs.com/. You just compile your template without generating html.

```
template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var html = template(yourdata);     // yourdata is the object rendered to your template
$('#app').html(html);   // can not be template variable, variable html is final html content
```